How to force stop and to unlock button while it is animating?
I have some funcs for the animation
func animateDownFloat(_ viewToAnimate: UIView, duration: Double = 0.2) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.2, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        })
    }
    
    func animateUpFloat(_ viewToAnimate: UIView, duration: Double = 0.15) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        })
    }

I have an IBAction that starts the animation
@IBAction func numberButtonTouchedDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
        animationsEngine.animateDownFloat(sender, duration: 0.5)
...
    }

The second IBAction returns the button to initial state
@IBAction func numberButtonTouchedUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        animationsEngine.animateUpFloat(sender, duration: 0.5)
...
    }

The thing is, when i tap the button before it returned to its initial state (before 0.5 secs ended) nothing happens, the animation does not force restart (numberButtonTouchedDown), other logic from touch down func doesn't start.
I tried using
sender.layer.removeAllAnimations()
adding flags, nothing changes

Did you try adding the .allowUserInteraction animation option?
